# Execute many mysql_query with time save

Tags: php, mysql

I try to execute many query at the same time but it take about 1-2 min to get crash. I also try to maximums the execution but using  `set_time_limit(120)` and it still crash. I have seen `mysqli_multi_query` would be a good choice but i don't know whether it s going to work with mine or not.

```
    mysql_query("UPDATE `lotto_gameplay` SET `six_digit_result`=1 WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT `lotto_main`.*,`lotto_gameplay`.* FROM `lotto_main` WHERE `lotto_main`.`lotto_num` = `lotto_gameplay`.`six_digit`  AND `lotto_main`.`postdate`='".$datt."'AND `lotto_main`.`lotto_type`='0' AND `lotto_gameplay`.`status`='0' )");

    mysql_query("UPDATE `lotto_gameplay` SET `six_digit_result`=2 WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT `lotto_main`.*,`lotto_gameplay`.* FROM `lotto_main` WHERE `lotto_main`.`lotto_num` = `lotto_gameplay`.`six_digit`  AND `lotto_main`.`postdate`='".$datt."'AND `lotto_main`.`lotto_type`='3' AND `lotto_gameplay`.`status`='0')");

    mysql_query("UPDATE `lotto_gameplay` SET `six_digit_result`=3 WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT `lotto_main`.*,`lotto_gameplay`.* FROM `lotto_main` WHERE `lotto_main`.`lotto_num` = `lotto_gameplay`.`six_digit`  AND `lotto_main`.`postdate`='".$datt."'AND `lotto_main`.`lotto_type`='4' AND `lotto_gameplay`.`status`='0')");


    mysql_query("UPDATE `lotto_gameplay` SET `six_digit_result`=4 WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT `lotto_main`.*,`lotto_gameplay`.* FROM `lotto_main` WHERE `lotto_main`.`lotto_num` = `lotto_gameplay`.`six_digit`  AND `lotto_main`.`postdate`='".$datt."'AND `lotto_main`.`lotto_type`='5' AND `lotto_gameplay`.`status`='0')");

    mysql_query("UPDATE `lotto_gameplay` SET `six_digit_result`=5 WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT `lotto_main`.*,`lotto_gameplay`.* FROM `lotto_main` WHERE `lotto_main`.`lotto_num` = `lotto_gameplay`.`six_digit`  AND `lotto_main`.`postdate`='".$datt."'AND `lotto_main`.`lotto_type`='6' AND `lotto_gameplay`.`status`='0')");

    mysql_query("UPDATE `lotto_gameplay` SET `six_digit_result`=6 WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT `lotto_main`.*,`lotto_gameplay`.* FROM `lotto_main` WHERE `lotto_main`.`lotto_num` = `lotto_gameplay`.`six_digit`  AND `lotto_main`.`postdate`='".$datt."'AND `lotto_main`.`lotto_type`='7' AND `lotto_gameplay`.`status`='0')");
```

Comment: Clash? did you mean crash, timeout, or what? What error you get from mysql_error()? If they crash as it is there is no point moving to multi_query it will crash as well, you need to first determinate why its crashing and optimize your query, then you decide if u need multi_query or not.

Comment: **Never use backticks around column names.**  They are just one more way for you to make syntax errors.  The only reason you need them is if you have a column name that is a reserved word, and using column names that are reserved words is a terrible idea as well, so that's two bad habits you can avoid at once.

Comment: If you want us to help optimize a query, **you need to show us the table and index definitions**, as well as row counts for each of the tables.  Maybe your tables are defined poorly.  Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly.  Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did.   Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell.  We also need row counts because that can affect query optimization greatly.

Comment: this is what it shown Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded

Comment: So the problem is that those 6 queries are taking longer than 30 seconds to execute, and you need to make them run faster.  In order to do that, you need to show us the table and index definitions.

Comment: Thank You Mr.Andy Lester ...in the second comment from you make me realise about that table missing the index column.It is work now.